# How to populate JNDI directory programatically in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, jndi

I was successful already inserting and finding objects in jndi directory across apps running in the same JVM with:

```
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        initialContext.bind("xpto",this);

        Object obj = initialContext.lookup("xpto");
```

Still I want to organise the namespace and therefore bind objects like:

```
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        initialContext.bind("/aaa/xpto",this);

        Object obj = initialContext.lookup("/aaa/xpto");
```

And this is failing with

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: aaa is not bound
```

I understand I may need to do something more to create the "aaa" node, but can't find anywhere what it is... most of the jetty documentation refers to statically defined objects which is not what I want. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Q: Have you looked at these links: [jetty:// - Configuring JNDI](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jndi.html), and [http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI)?  In particular, what's in your "WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml"?

Comment: Yes, I went through them all. The focus there is on java:comp schemes for configuration file initialization and configuration of resource managers. In my case I want to populate programatically the namespace and nothing is mentioned other than java:comp/env ...

Comment: I've never tried to create a JNDI name without also making an entry in one or more of service.xml, web.xml, META-INF/context.xml (or, in your case) jetty-web.xml. Q: Is there any reason you don't want to edit jetty-web.xml?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to share between webapps running in same JVM  instances of objects that are known only at runtime on the logic of the program. There is nothing I know about these entities at compile time to put them in static configuration.

Comment: Dynamically change JNDI bindings at runtime?  Sure!  You can do that.  Dynamically create new JNDI resources at runtime? Then I'm not sure JNDI is what you want.  Here is a link from somebody with a similar question (if I'm understanding you correctly) - he decided to go with something other than JNDI: http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-dynamically-create-JNDI-Context-Resources-td2033298.html.  Q: Have you considered something like [MongoDB](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions below, but what I wanted is simply to hold a small cache to object instances within same jvm, without bloating the application. Of course the alternative is to make my own cache with some support of hierarchy, but if jndi is there just wanted to re-use it. I've made some progresses and understand now the concept of createSubcontext, and what I see now is that I can do what I want inside same webapp, BUT I can't bind objects to JVM scope programatically, the same way that is possible through the configuration.

Comment: Something I found : it seemed that what I wanted could be possible in jboss with "java:global/" context, but jetty doc seems to imply that only a "java:comp" is supported...

Comment: Thanks FoggyDay and everyone else. This turned out to be much puzzling than the only thing which I wanted to achieve which was some kind of "Hierarchical Hashmap" available to all the webapps. Going the easy route and implementing something simpler in a Lifecycle instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to dynamically create name/value pairs (resource name/resource value) at runtime, then share them between different processes.

If so, MongoDB (or something like it) might be exactly what you're looking for.

Here's a brief tutorial:

- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily with an LDAP server.